# No visible selection in xamarin.forms Collectionview on android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this xaml collectionView code. I get visible selection on uwp but not on android 9.

```
            <CollectionView Grid.Row="6" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" x:Name="searchResultCollection" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource listViewGridStyle}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding BindingContext.SearchResultSelectionChangedCommand, Source={x:Reference searchResultCollection}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Start" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource listViewLabelStyle}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Start, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeToString}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource listViewLabelStyle}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SearchMatchLabel}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource listViewLabelStyle}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SearchMatchHighlight}" TextType="Html" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource listViewLabelStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

I have updated to the current Xamarin.Forms Version, but the problem is still there. Any Ideas?

Update: I have added the selected background to my style, but it still doesn't work. I have try it with uwp with orange as backgroundColor, but light blue is displayed. It looks like that State does not change to Selected

```
 <Style x:Key="listViewGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="RowSpacing">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="0.1" Tablet="5" Desktop="5"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ColumnSpacing">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="2" Tablet="10" Desktop="10"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Solution: I have added the Tapped Event

```
                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"  Command="{Binding BindingContext.SearchResultSelectionChangedCommand, Source={x:Reference searchResultCollection}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

and in the code behind file I change the State manually:

```
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var nextSelected = sender as VisualElement;
        if (_previousSelected != null) VisualStateManager.GoToState(_previousSelected, "Normal");
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(nextSelected, "Selected");
        _previousSelected = nextSelected;
    }
```

Comment: You can set the [selected item color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your Grid has a `listViewGridStyle`. I assume your grid has a backgroundColor so the default selected item color will not work. You need to [Change selected item color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color) by yourself.

Example is here:

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                        SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

> The Style that contains the Selected VisualState must have a
>   TargetType property value that's the type of the root element of the
>   DataTemplate, which is set as the ItemTemplate property value.

Try it and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have try it and it doesn't work (see my updated Question) . It looks like that the State is not changing to Selected. Changing the BackgroundColor for the Normal State works fine

Comment: I just tried your code and found out that it does not work because there is a TapGestureRecognizer  on your Grid. When you click the cell, the command is raised and the cell does not been selected, so the background does not change. If you hold on the tap for a bit more time, then the color will change.